# Why does a field(liked_songs) show for a userprofile in admin/ but not when I query the database

Tags: django, django-views

`ORM queries`

```
>>> from comparison.models import UserProfile, Song, Album
>>> UserProfile.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<UserProfile: kb>, <UserProfile: Daniella>]>
 >>> Song.objects.all().values_list("pk", flat=True)            st'
 <QuerySet [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, '...(remaining 
 elements truncated)...']>    6, 17, 18, 19, 20, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
>>> UserProfile.objects.get(id=2)
<UserProfile: Daniella>
>>> UserProfile.objects.get(id=2).liked_songs.all()[0:20]
<QuerySet []>
>>> UserProfile.objects.get(id=1)
<UserProfile: kb>
>>> UserProfile.objects.get(id=1).liked_songs.all()[0:5]
<QuerySet [<Song: Emotionally Scarred>, <Song: Lonely Child>, <Song: Really Love>, <Song: Another 
Life>, <Song: Bitches Ain't 
Shit>]>
>>>
```

`models.py`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None , null= True)
   liked_songs = models.ManyToManyField("Song", null=True , default=None,  
related_name="users_that_liked_me")
   class Meta:
    db_table = "UserProfile"

   def __str__(self):
     return self.user.first_name


class Album(models.Model):
   Album_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)  

class Meta:
    db_table= "Album"

def __str__(self):
    return self.Album_name

class Song(models.Model):
  track_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  artiste_name= models.CharField(
  max_length=200)
  album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None, related_name = 
"songs")

class Meta:
    db_table="Song"

def __str__(self):
    return self.track_name
```

`views.py(one which uses the models)`

```
 def liked(request):

   try:
    sp = Spotify(auth_manager=oauth)
    liked = sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=30)['items']
    spotify_user = sp.current_user()
    user__ , created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=spotify_user['uri'], 
    first_name=spotify_user["display_name"])
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user__)[0]
        

    a = []

    for idx, item in enumerate(liked):
        track = item['track']["name"]
        artist= item["track"]["artists"][0]["name"]
        album_ = item["track"]["album"]["name"]
        tracks = item['track']
        val = tracks['name'] + " - " + tracks['artists'][0]['name']
        a.append(val)

        album = Album.objects.get_or_create(
           Album_name= album_ 
        )[0].save()
      
        song, created = Song.objects.get_or_create(track_name = track,
        artiste_name = artist,
        album = album)

        if not created:
            user__.userprofile.liked_songs.add(song)
    
    return HttpResponse("<br>".join(a))

 except SpotifyException:
    return redirect(reverse("login"))
```

`AIM`: To store liked songs for each user. When I open `admin/`, it shows the same liked_songs for each `UserProfile`, which is not the aim. I want it to show liked_songs for each user distinctively. And when I run queries in `shell`, I get empty Querysets for one profile and a list for the other profile whilst the `admin/`site says otherwise. Is there an issue with my model relationships or is it the way I add the songs to the model in my `views`? Thanks

[image: First Profile]
[image: Second Profile]

Comment: in the admin, it will show all songs, but only those grayed out is the one specific for your user.

Comment: @ha-neul none are grayed out

Comment: @ha-neul okay i just saw.